# Closure unexpectedly demands throw (Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, error-handling, firebase-realtime-database, closures

So I am using Firebase to pull JSON and turn it into an array of `GasUse` objects.

This is the `GasUse` class. It's initializer accepts a `Dictionary` and throws an error, when a key:value pair is missing.

```
class GasUse {

   let distance: Double
   let comment: String?
   let addedByUser: String
   let creationDate: Date


   init(from jsonDict: [String:Any]) throws {
       guard let distance = jsonDict["distance"] as? Double else { throw SerializationError.missing }
       let comment = jsonDict["comment"] as? String
       guard let addedByUser = jsonDict["addedByUser"] as? String else { throw SerializationError.missing }
       guard let creationDateString = jsonDict["creationDate"] as? String else { throw SerializationError.missing }

       self.distance = distance
       self.comment = comment
       self.addedByUser = addedByUser
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
       self.creationDate = dateFormatter.date(from: creationDateString)!
   }
}
```

I then use this code to create the `GasUse`try

```
Database.database().reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { //Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataSnapshot) -> Void'(rootSnapshot) in
    let childSnapshots = rootSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    let childValues = childSnapshots.map { $0.value as! [String: Any] }

    for value in childValues {
        do { let gasUse = try GasUse(from: value) }
        catch SerializationError.missing { self.present(self.makeAlert("Error", "Missing value in json"), animated: true, completion: nil) }
        catch SerializationError.invalid { self.present(self.makeAlert("Error", "Invalid value in json"), animated: true, completion: nil) }
        }

    })
```

But the function seems to demand a specific format for its closure, that I think I am following though.

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataSnapshot) -> Void'(rootSnapshot) in

**What is wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

Compiler thinks your "try" block could throw some error that will not be captured by two specific "catch" instructions. So from compiler's point of view your closure is a throwing one. To fix it just add a third catch that will catch everything:

```
do { let gasUse = try GasUse(from: value) }
catch SerializationError.missing { self.present(self.makeAlert("Error", "Missing value in json"), animated: true, completion: nil) }
catch SerializationError.invalid { self.present(self.makeAlert("Error", "Invalid value in json"), animated: true, completion: nil) }
catch error { 
    // print() or assert() if you want to control such a case
}
```